# Make YcmCompleter GoTo automatically unfold

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

When I use YcmCompleter GoTo with foldmethod=syntax, it doesn't unfold the new file. Hence, I often end up far from the actual location. Is there a way to make it automatically unfold and go to the correct line when using this command?
Adding different foldopens doesn't work and I don't want to set foldopen to all as I rely on vertical navigations past folds quite often.

Answer (score 0):

From the [folding docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'foldopen'):

```
NOTE: When the command is part of a mapping this option is not used.
Add the |zv| command to the mapping to get the same effect.
(rationale: the mapping may want to control opening folds itself)
```

Then, to get that behaviour, you could add something like this to your .vimrc:

`noremap gt :YcmCompleter GoToDefinition<CR>zv`